# What do the different QMessageBox.Roles mean?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I am exploring the behavior of a custom warning message box, to which I add different buttons using:

```
msgBox.addButton(<button text>, QtGui.QMessageBox.XRole)
```

Where the different possible roles (i.e., values of X) are [enumerated at the documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html#ButtonRole-enum).

My question is, what is the status of these roles, exactly, and what are the rules for their usage? I cannot find anything explicit in the documentation, and when I use any role other than `Destructive`, `Accept`, or `Reject`, when `QMessageBox` executes it does not seem to be returning the Role properly, as in the following simple example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class Form(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        #Make a few buttons
        warnButton=QtGui.QPushButton("Warn Me")
        self.readoutLabel=QtGui.QLabel("Waiting for inputs from dialog")
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout() 
        layout.addWidget(warnButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.readoutLabel)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        warnButton.clicked.connect(self.warnSlot)

    def warnSlot(self):
        self.readoutLabel.setText("Waiting for inputs from dialog")
        msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox(QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning,  
                "QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Warning...)", "Will you heed this fancy custom warning?!",
                QtGui.QMessageBox.NoButton, self)
        msgBox.addButton("Accept", QtGui.QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
        msgBox.addButton("I reject you!", QtGui.QMessageBox.RejectRole)
        msgBox.addButton("Destroy!", QtGui.QMessageBox.DestructiveRole)  
        msgBox.addButton("Yes!", QtGui.QMessageBox.YesRole)
        reply=msgBox.exec_()  #seems to always be 0,1, or 2
        print "Actual reply: " , reply
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.DestructiveRole:  
            self.readoutLabel.setText("Response to warning: Destroy")
        elif reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.RejectRole:
            self.readoutLabel.setText("Response to warning: Reject")
        elif reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.AcceptRole:  
            self.readoutLabel.setText("Response to warning: Accept")
        elif reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.YesRole:
            self.readoutLabel.setText("Response to warning: Yes")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qtApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(qtApp.exec_())
```

When you click the 'Yes' button, as opposed to the other buttons, it does not seem to be registered by the caller. It doesn't seem these Roles are inert, but have underlying mechanics and usage expectations to which I am blind.

Answer (score 6):

The return value of `QMessageBox::exec` only makes sense if you're using standard buttons in the dialog. But you're technically using custom buttons, in which case `exec()` returns button index (but you shouldn't rely on this fact either because it's not fixed in the documentation). Correct results for buttons other than 'yes' button is merely a coincidence. If you put adding 'accept' button after adding 'reject' button, you will start to receive incorrect results for these buttons too.

You can use `QMessageBox::buttonRole` and `QMessageBox::currentButton` to get actual role:

```
msgBox.exec_()
reply = msgBox.buttonRole(msgBox.clickedButton())
```

If you have multiple buttons with the same role, you can save each button object and compare `QMessageBox::currentButton` to each button object:

```
yes_button = msgBox.addButton("Yes!", QtGui.QMessageBox.YesRole)
msgBox.exec_()
if msgBox.clickedButton() == yes_button:
  print("Response to warning: Yes")
```

The purpose of button roles is to provide platform-consistent look and feel for message boxes. Positions of buttons will vary depending on their roles and current OS. For example, 'help' button will appear to the left or to the right depending on where it usually appear in native dialogs on current OS.

Note: `exec()` would give correct results if you use standard buttons. Curiously I didn't find a way to use them in PySide: `QMessageBox::addButton(StandardButton)` is not available in PySide; `QMessageBox::setStandardButtons` doesn't seem to have any effect; using 'buttons' argument of the constructor works incorrectly. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: years later it is still a problem, while Qt documentation actually says that return value of exec is defined by button role, it still doesnt work with custom buttons